# Swagger-Swashbuckle include xmlcomments from dependent dlls

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

I need to document an asp.net core web api and I m using swagger and swashbuckle.

I have looked around and I have found this link but it's old and does not work
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/93

Can somebody show/point me how i can include xml comments from another dll?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two versions of swashbuckle:

- https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle
- https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

If the tags on this question are correct, your link is not to the version you are using, but still the solution offered should give you a good idea what you need to do.

You can include as many xml comments as you want with `IncludeXmlComments` that is still available on Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, see here:
[Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/Application/SwaggerGenOptions.cs#L259](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/Application/SwaggerGenOptions.cs#L259)

First you need to make sure that the xml comments you need are making it to the server as part of your deployment,  otherwise Swashbuckle will not show what it is not there...

A solution could be to recursively loop looking for XML files and add them using the IncludeXmlComments, something like this:

```
public void IncludeAllXmlComments(string folder)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(folder))
  {
    foreach (var name in Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.XML", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
      IncludeXmlComments(filePath: name);
    }
  }
}
```

This sample code is just to give you an idea, not for copy/pasta

Comment: Hi thanks for your time I am using Swashbucke.AspNetCore(2.4.0) ,which I assume is the latest correct version for asp.net core web api.Correct? Would be the solution to output the xmlcomments for each dll to a specific shared directory and read it from there?

Comment: @developer9969 Yes for both, the xmlcomments for all your dll should be already outputing to the same location the dll is at, by default that is : `project\bin\Debug` or Release depending on your build settings

Comment: correct.They already do. but looking at your pseudo code you were passing a folder and then getting all the files.which I thought implied that all dll.xmlcomments were outputting to a designated folder rather than the default bin/debig/release dir

Comment: @developer9969 Key point on my code is: `Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.XML", SearchOption.AllDirectories)` that will get all .xml files in the folder and any subfolder of the given folder, so the idea is to give a folder as high level as you can, and let the GetFiles do the work for you, (I'm assuming you don't have millon files in your folder, that will be bad, very bad)